# pythonのデバッガー（pdb）において、関数スコープ内でglobal変数をいじっても、維持されませんか？

Tags: python

vscodeでpdbの挙動を調べるのに以下のようなコードをつかって、遊んでいました。
下から二行目のprint("start")にブレークポイントをもってきてスタートさせ、
step intoで進んでいきます。
a=100のあと、print(a)にカーソルが来たときに、
GUI操作で、a=1000とすると、いったんは、数字が更新されますが、すぐに100に戻ってしまいます。（更新されていない？）
そもそもDEBUG CONSOLEからだと、グローバル変数を更新できません。
pdbにおいて、関数内において、DEBUG CONSOLEなどを使って、グローバル変数に値を入力したり、更新する方法はあるのでしょうか？

```
def main():
    global a
    a=100
    print(a)
    func1()


def func1():
    b=200
    print(b)
    func2()

def func2():    
    c=300
    print(c)
    func3()

def func3():
    d=400
    print(d)

print("start")
main()
```

Comment: global scope にある変数の値を変更するのですから `exec('global a; a = 1000')` とすれば一応できます。

Comment: 関数内にいるときにそれをやってもできませんでした。

Comment: 参考までに、こちらの環境は Python 3.9.5 でコマンドラインから PDB を動作させています。

Comment: もしかしたらこれらの記事が参考になるかも。[VS Code : Python 3 : How do you change a variable whilst debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50541955/9014308), [Data inspection](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_data-inspection)

Comment: ちなみに「いったんは、数字が更新されますが、すぐに100に戻ってしまいます。」というのは、どういう操作をどういう順番で行った時にどの時点で発生しているのでしょう？ その辺を追記してみてください。例えばこの記事 [global変数の使い方について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/45521/26370) の2つの回答に示されたような状況に陥っていませんか？

Comment: すいません　結局、スタックフレームの理解が足りなかったようです　gdbのデバッグ本を見て理解しました。スタックをグローバルにきりかえることで、グローバル変数の代入ができました　そうしないと関数からでたとたんに消えてしまいます

Comment: 解決したなら、他の人のために、どんなところや手順が間違っていて、何をしたら目的が達成できたのかといった詳細を自己回答してみてください。

Comment: いずれにしろみなさんコメントありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

`main()` の中の `print` にさしかかったときに、デバッグコンソールから `global a;a=1000` としても反映されませんし、単にVARIABLES枠で `a:100⇛1000` に修正しても、`print` 関数のアウトプットには反映されません。

CALL STACK枠で、対象となるスタックフレーム（今回のように関数の階層になっている場合どのレベルにいるか、グローバル変数なら一番外。）に変更してから上記を入力する必要があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]